# "other" or "the other" in this sentence

Tags: articles, adjectives, definite-article

I wrote:

> Each pattern can be designated either for data extraction purpose or for restricting the occurrence of **other** patterns.

Here, *other* could mean the remaining patterns (the rest), or maybe the other different patterns. Anyway, I feel I have a problem when I should use "the" before "other".

Comment: @Chris the 'proofreading' close reason explicitly states *unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified.*

Comment: @Chris you're welcome. I also removed my comment. I try to respect the website rules, though I can't deny that I welcome any advice on my sentences but that's not my initial purpose.

Comment: I don't see before in your sentence. That said, the rule is this: if you have already mentioned /a pattern, not each pattern/, the next reference to other ones would be: before the other patterns [in  your text] or before other patterns [in general, not restricted to your text]. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Lambie it seems I should use "the other" because I talk about a set of patterns created in an application. (However it is not determined how many they are)

Comment: @Ahman Sorry, can't help you beyond what I have already said.

Answer (score 3):

> Each pattern can be designated either for data extraction purpose or for restricting the occurrence of **the** other patterns.

If you use **the**, the phrase will imply a set of patterns that has already been described in some way.

An example:

> In Judaism, the Torah is accorded the highest level of sanctity, above that of **the other books** of the Bible. ([Google Books](https://books.google.ru/books?id=yErYBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT57&dq=%22of%20the%20other%20books%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQjrz_7_vQAhXHDywKHbGIAGsQ6AEIcTAL#v=onepage&q=%22of%20the%20other%20books%22&f=false))

We can transform this excerpt:

> There are 24 books in the Hebrew Bible. In Judaism, the Torah is accorded the highest level of sanctity, above that of **the other books**.

We will understand "the other books" to mean "the other 23 books of the Bible".

If we wrote:

> In Judaism, the Torah is accorded the highest level of sanctity, above that of **other books**.

The phrase "other books" would mean "all other books in general".

---

Related:

- [The other vs. other: which article to choose?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11059/the-other-other)
- [Exxon and the other supermajors are more vulnerable than they look](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/8649/2127)
- [The other chapters vs other chapters](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/79514/2127)

Comment: Couldn't "above that of other books" mean above other religions books of Judaism? I mean when the context is specified but the set is not specified which should be used "other" or "the other"?

Comment: @Ahmad - Indeed, since the general context is specified (Judaism), it may be taken to mean "above the other religious books of Judaism". Nice point.